# Torrenting crashes internet connection

Tags: networking, bittorrent, utorrent

This only started happening recently, when I torrent something it crashes the router after a while. I noticed with uTorrent it happens almost immediatly and with qBittorrent only after like 10 minutes.
I have to reset the router to get it to work again.

IP flooding protection is off and I cant find anything in my router settings that would limit connections in any way. The weird thing is, it worked fine until like half a month ago, and I didnt really change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Posting your torrent client will get you better answers on how to configure it according to the isp bandwidth you have.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the number of simultaneous connections in your bittorrent client.  What is likely happening is that in the router the open connection list table is getting full and once full can no longer accept new connections until some of the existing ones time out.

See: [Here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/stop-bittorrent-from-killing-your-internet-connection/).

Comment: Agreed. Set the number of connections from the torrent client to 125 and even older routers should not crash.
However, a current generation router should handle many hundreds of open concurrent connections with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Routers contain stateful NATs and firewalls. Which means they keep state for each "connection".

Sadly, connection here often also means that every single, normally stateless UDP request-reply exchange is tracked as a separate connection, despite [RFC 4787](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4787) prescribing endpoint-independent mappings (EIM), i.e. just one mapping per port.

The DHT feature implemented in most bittorrent clients does many such exchanges to many different IPs which can lead to overflows of the connection tracking tables and subsequently to crashes/hangs/other temporary disruptions.

In theory enabling UPnP on the router or manually mapping the ports can help if that changes its behavior to use EIMs. But again, not all routers implement that.

> IP flooding protection is off

It is unlikely to help unless you have IPv6, since NAT would still be enabled, but you could still try completely disabling its firewall.

Answer (score 0):

oddly, i found that torrenting over wifi buried (caused it to crash and reboot) my router within minutes, but when i was hardlined (ethernet cable connexion), it had no problem.  i literally moved my office and while i was waiting for hardlines (ethernet cable connexion) to get run, i was running wifi for the first time in forever.  router kept dying and i thought it was toast.  once hardlines (ethernet cable connexion) were in, problem went away.  so it might also be the crappy wifi drivers on the router.  for reference, i was running an ASUS RT-AC68U.  i've since migrated to Mikrotik and, well, no stupid wifi issues anymore.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).